# Batch copy character

Tags: batch-file, copy

So, I'm trying to make a folder with a load of batch files, each individually will copy a certain character to the clipboard. My first one was ñ. I made a batch file that runs the script

`echo|set/p=ñ|clip`

But on running the batch file ├▒   <- is copied to my clipboard.

Anyone know why and what I should change in the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to change the batch file to use UTF-8 by putting
`chcp 65001`
at the start of the batch file.